# JQuery Post changes json data to query string

Tags: jquery, http-post

I am doing a **JSON POST** via `$.post()`, but it seems it is changing my **POST** contents from **JSON** to **Query string parameters**.

I POST the following to the end-point:

```
$.post('/proxy/endpoint.json', { "query": {"test": true, "msg": "test" } });
```

The server handling the request shows the following logs:

```
ERROR - Bad POST params: query%5Btest%5D=true&query%5Dmsg%5Btest
```

#### Request flow:

> JavaScript -> IIS Rewrite Proxy -> Nginx -> Java Server endpoint, `e.g. localhost:4000/endpoint.json`

**NOTE:** I've tested the same POST request via **Postman** directly to **IIS Server**, which works fine. So it can only be my Jquery which is causing this problem.

Any tips on how I can improve this?

Comment: Your code POSTs fine for me when I try it. Can you share the rest of your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the answer was to use the **string representation** of the JSON object.

```
$.post('/proxy/endpoint.json', JSON.stringify({ "query": {"test": true, "msg": "test" } }));
```

This turned out to work.

Thanks to **Ahmed El-sayed** for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

back to [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) , and pass the right params object

for you example change your code to

```
$.post('/proxy/endpoint', {"test": true, "msg": "test" });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the JSON object being passed through, as the server is expecting it in that format.

Comment: don't pass it directly to jQuery.Post , try to use it as " SERVERJSON.query " . use only the value of query in JSON object passed through

Comment: I got a hint from your response, thus what you meant was to use the string representation of the JSON object.

Comment: Yes, what i mean to use string of json object and pass the value of key " query " (ex: obj.query)